# Can't connect to SQL Server DB from Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, progress, datadirect

I am having a difficult time trying to connect to a SQL Server DB on Linux, using pyodbc.  I have a ODCINI file entry created.  I started with this:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DSN;Database=DB;UID=UID;PWD=PWD')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.tableA')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

which throws this error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to set SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING attribute.
```

I googled that error and added this line after reading some recommendations:

```
pyodbc.pooling=False
```

So script changed to this:

```
import pyodbc

pyodbc.pooling=False

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DSN;Database=DB;UID=UID;PWD=PWD')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.tableA')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Which resulted in this:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] 䑛瑡䑡物捥嵴佛䉄⁃楬嵢匠数楣楦摥搠楲敶\u2072潣汵\u2064潮⁴敢氠慯敤d\uffff\uffff㢸ꔻ罱\x00\ue5b8鮫罱\x00㳰ꔻ罱\x00\uffff\uffff罱\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00鳭ꕞ罱\x00塰ꕉ罱 (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

At the suggestion of a coworker I added these 2 lines AFTER the pyodbc.connect line:

```
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1', to=str)
conn.setencoding(str, encoding='latin1')
```

I tried that with both latin1 and utf-8.  Neither work, still throws the same interface error with Chinese characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first part of the error message converted from "Chinese" UTF-16LE to Windows-1252 comes out as "[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded". First, verify that your Linux environment is in the "Operating System Support" list [here](https://www.progress.com/odbc/microsoft-sql-server#technical-specifications). If so, then try following the steps in the tutorial [here](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/odbc/sql-server-odbc-driver-for-linux-quick-start-guide).

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson.  I think you hit the nail on the head, it seems to be a  driver issue. Specifically a data direct driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with same description `RuntimeError: Unable to set SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING attribute`. I had no clue what is happening and why is happening. After lot of debugging i was able to figure it out why.

**Simple answer is :**
Reinstall the `unixODBC drivers` or/and `SQL drivers`.

**Reason why :**
When install the ODBC Drivers first and then SQL related drivers, sometimes it override the symlinks in Unix system.  You can find out more info on this from [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) official [GitHub issue#847](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/847#issuecomment-733074573) .

Answer (score 0):

you can simply uninstall and then do:

```
conda install unixodbc
```